how to filter out error table in a list power query
Can I request your help? I have a list which contains tables and some are showing as error. I am trying to filter the list to exclude error items but I can't figure out how.
Appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks.
enter image description here
I tried to convert the list into a table with one column and do Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Converted to Table", {"Column1"}) but it didn't work.
